# Search Results not displaying for multiple word search

Tags: theme-development, search

I've customized a theme and am having some problems with search results using multiple-word queries. Site is live at [www.abetterworldbydesign.com](http://abetterworldbydesign.com)

[Searching for a single word](http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/?s=press) works as expected.

[Searching for multiple words](http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/?s=press%20releases) that should have returned results shows blank results.

Oddly enough, [manually changing the "+" character in the URL to "&"](http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/?s=press&releases) displays the results correctly but only shows the first word in the header "Search results for:_".

My code in search.php for initializing WP_Query follows exactly [the code listed in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Preserving_Search_Page_Results_and_Pagination). Full code for [search.php on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tjGsDePY).

Code for searchform.php below.

```
<form id="searchform" name="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'richwp' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the correct way to search for multiple words is with a `+`, anything you add on with an `&` will get treated as a seperate query paramter. I'm not 100% sure though.. been a while since i've examined the search code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Richard M on the [question originally asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819226/search-results-not-displaying-for-multiple-word-search-in-wordpress):

Replacing line 21 on [search.php](http://pastebin.com/tjGsDePY) with `$search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1])` resolved it.